# How to pass passwords as parameters in a method

Tags: c#, string, passwords

I have the method login() below that accepts two parameters, username and password. I plan to use this method in another class but I am not sure if there is any convention when passing passwords to a method. Should I use a different datatype for the password? And am I using it correctly when I try to call the method?

```
class Libary {

    public string login(string username, string password) {
              externalObject.WriteLine("login {0} {1}", username, password);
              string response = externalObject.Execute();
              return response;
    }

}

class HomePage {

     public string callLoginMethod(){
               string username = "dummyUsername";
               string password = "dummyPassword";

               Library library = new Library();
               string output = library.login(username, password);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Marc Gravell you should use SecureString. You can use the code below

class Libary
    {

```
    public string login(System.Security.SecureString username, System.Security.SecureString password)
    {
        externalObject.WriteLine("login {0} {1}", username, password);
        string response = externalObject.Execute();
        return response;
    }

}

class SecureLibrary {

    public System.Security.SecureString GetSecureString(string text)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString strSecure = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            strSecure.AppendChar(c);
        }
        return strSecure;
    }
}

class HomePage
{

    public string callLoginMethod()
    {
        string username = "dummyUsername";
        string password = "dummyPassword";

        Library library = new Library();
        SecureLibrary seclib = new SecureLibrary();
        string output = library.login(seclib.GetSecureString(username), seclib.GetSecureString(password));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for this! I was actually looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Actually one tries to work with SecureString as soon as possible, having it in a string first somehow neglects the purpose of SecureString, ideally this transformation isn't necessary at all. The [PasswordBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword(v=vs.110).aspx) for example provides a SecureString and with some tricks you can even bind to this property, avoiding having the password in a string at all.

Comment: @martinstoeckli `SecureString` is not secure; sure, it makes it *more inconvenient* (you can't spot them *quite as easily* with a memory scanner), but: they are completely and trivially reversible once located, and .NET-aware tooling can do the same thing the GC does (or "SOS") to find objects along with their types. If anything, it makes it easier to find them, as you know that anything that is a `SecureString` is probably interesting, which is not the case for `string`. But: in all these cases (were `SecureString` is relevant): the box is already compromised. You've *already lost*.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes I know (and voted for your answer), just wanted to point out, that using SecureString with having the password in a string first, neglects the small advantage we would have otherwise (deterministic behaviour without waiting on the carbage collector).

Comment: @MarcGravell wait sorry, I am kind of confused. So the solution above is not ideal? Will using char make a difference? What about if the password is not in a string first? I'm not really familiar with security in coding so I would like to know more about this if it's okay.

Comment: @thecodeexplorer define "OK"? what threat are you protecting from? It is impossible to talk about security without knowing "from what". In any cases where `string` would be a problem, the entire machine is compromised, and all bets are already off - unless you have something very specific in mind

Comment: @thecodeexplorer - Have a look at the documentation [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx#HowSecure) it is explained very well, the pros and the cons. The SecureString can reduce the time, the password can be extracted from the memory, but if there are already other uncontrollable copies in the memory, there is no point in this. As MarcGravell wrote, the advantage is a bit moot, because the computer must be compromised already.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use passwords, that is usually fine. There *are* some scenarios where it might be useful to keep them as a `char[]` so they can be overwritten (zero'd) easily afterwards, or as `SecureString` - but frankly both of these only help in very specific scenarios where the machine running the code is already completely compromised, and all they do is make it *more inconvenient* for an attacker. So in most real world cases: `string` is fine.

Of course, if you can *avoid* having to know plain text passwords at all (certs, windows auth, app-keys, etc) - then that might be a way of avoiding the problem.

Comment: There is a good explanation for [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) and a link with a discussion about its usefulness. It also depends on the target platform whether the SecureString can be used or not.

Comment: I see, thanks for the thorough explanation and the tips!